# How to share android gradle libraries from cache and build from them

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio, gradle

I'm unable to download android gradle libraries due to firewall, how can I copy the libraries from another pc and use them from local when building.

Answer (score 0):

You can try copying contents inside .gradle directory from another PC in which gradle libraries are already downloaded. In a linux machine, by default .gradle directory will be in your home folder. In windows and MAC also location of .gradle directory will be somewhere similar.

Comment: If I keep it inside my git repo under 'jars' folder, how to tell gradle to use this instead of downloading from web.

Comment: From android studio you can change gradle path from Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Project Level Settings ->  Use Local gradle distribution